# Are there any tools/APIs to check consistency of a windows cluster?

Tags: cluster, windows-cluster

Things to be checked:

- Directory structures (recursive, with any attributes and properties)
- Configuration (equiv and partial conf, format specific or generic, with regex)
- Registry (presence of keys, same/diff values etc)
- Services (specific ones by name/pattern, status - running, stopped, autostart etc)
- Scheduled tasks

Yes, you can check some of these with monitoring systems and templates quite effectively (for example services running/not). However, you need to be able to have comprehensive diffs view for things like Directory Structures, Config files etc, which is limited by restricted views of monitoring tools (usually traffic light & short description - as it should be).

You will only run these comprehensive consistency checks on demand, for example after a deployment.

Comment: A well-designed monitoring system with checks for critical services, in combination with configuration management is what you're looking for.

Comment: what if its a new setup or a 5+ member cluster in an existing DHACM (don't have anything clever mate) configuration and one just wants to see what is the difference by specifying dirs, conf file paths, registry paths, service names and schedule task names to a system which then connects and visually represents the differences?